# Get Facebook friends last status

Tags: android, facebook

How can i get a friends last status in **Facebook** ?

```
Request r = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(
            ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), new GraphUserListCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                        Response response) {
                    if (users != null) {
                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ll.startAnimation(fadein);
                        ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        friends = users;
                        f = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                            f.add(users.get(i).getName());
                        }
                        loadRandom();
                    }
                }
            });
    Bundle params = r.getParameters();
    params.putString("fields", "name,id,gender");
    r.setParameters(params);
    r.executeAsync();
```

I am using this code, but how can i get their status ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
params.putString("fields", "name,id,gender,statuses.limit(1)");
```

to achieve this. Remember that you need the "user_status" permission to do this.